# problem in loading bootstrap 3 modal in woo-commerce

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, notice

I'm updating a 2 year old woocommerce template (WordPress) and for the notices template I have this code:

```js
<script>
    jQuery(function ($) {
      $(window).load(function(){
        $(window).on('load', function () {
          $('#mymessage').modal('show');
        });
</script>
```

```html
<div id="mymessage" class="modal-message modal fade" role="dialog">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-body">
            <i class="fa fa-times-circle-o"></i>
            <ul>
               <?php foreach ( $messages as $message ) : ?>
               <li><?php echo wp_kses_post( $message ); ?></li>
               <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

The problem is with the js part. I tried both `$` or `jQuery` @ per line start but the result is the same.
No process of javascript on page and in result "js" codes posted inline and not run

ps. jQuery itself loaded correctly in footer

Any correction to js part is most appreciated

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  $('#mymessage').modal('show');
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="container">
      <button id="btnTest" class="btn btn-default">Show Modal</button>
      <div id="mymessage" role="dialog" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="close">&times;</button>
              <h4 class="modal-title">Error</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <p>Your data here </p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default">Close</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```